# Are Parse push notifications very unreliable? Only 50% of mine are received

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I am building an app that will implement a Parse backend to send push notifications. Users will be able to send other users a message contained in a push notification. I have been playing around with this and when I send it registers on the Parse website fine but only about 50% of the messages sent are being received on the device. Does anyone else have this problem? I know Push Notifications are not guaranteed but a 50% success rate? Any ideas?

Thanks

code below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [Parse setApplicationId:@"***"
    clientKey:@"****"];

    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes =     (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                   UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];


return YES;

}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}

- (void)notifyFriendAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(userCompletionHandler)handler
{

    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];

    NSString *pushMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From %@ HI!", self.currentUser.username];
    NSDictionary *pushData = @{@"alert": pushMessage, @"badge": @0, @"sound": @"notify.wav"};
    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setQuery:pushQuery];
    [push setData:pushData];
    [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            handler(NO, error);
        }
        else {
            handler(YES, nil);
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a user end issue, parse.com has proven to be loyal to it's foundation so far. Show some relevant code on how your sending them. are you defining channels, users etc?

Comment: Added my code above, the AppDelegate methods and my notify method. Right now a user can send a Push to all the iOS devices (just for testing purposes). Does it look okay?

Comment: looks ok. Again, not saying they are perfect, but they are one of the better ones out there for a reason, and they haven't proven unreliable in the past. If the problem persists you should submit a ticket to the them so they can investigate.  But just take a close look around your app, it still feels like a user end issue at this point. How are you tracking your push success rate?

Comment: might have fixed it actually....when pasting the code I noticed that userinfo was on a new line and not next to (NSDictionary*), maybe I accidentally hit return. Not sure why Xcode let me compile that though...and not sure why it would make a difference. Anyway I have corrected it. Just spend 20 mins testing so far have a 100% success rate! Don't want to say for sure just yet it's fixed might just be a fluke but this is a dramatic change. Never had 100% before. Fingers crossed......odd error –

Comment: I track the success rate just by looking at the push section on my Parse.com control panel. There is says if the push is delivered to the device or not. So far so good.

Comment: Yes I know, but i'm asking your getting a success rate sent from the device 50% of the time? or all together from you backend it's 50% (website + device pushes) and how are you tracking it? If it's the first it's a coding issue, if it's the latter there are numerous variables you could troubleshoot

Comment: oh, it was 50% sent from devices to begin with. didn't do much testing. seems like since that code fix I am getting 100% now though. Not a single one missed.

Comment: yeah it's dropped again now. no longer 100%...could it be a bad wifi connection? If a push is sent and the wifi doesn't pick it up does it keep trying or is it once chance only? That would maybe make sense then..My wifi isn't the best...

Comment: maybe it's dependent on the time of the day...

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced any major problems in the past with Parse's Push Notification delivery.  One of my apps has about 32,000 registered devices and seems to get near 100% delivery.

I also have a couple of chat apps that use Parse as the messaging and push back-end.  Users can subscribe to a particular chat room and get Push Notification through Segmentation.  One of those apps just launched and so far the push notifications are coming through 100%.  The only thing I've noticed is a slight delay sometimes.  Maybe a minute or two, but I think that could be because of a slow wifi connection.

I also use PushWoosh for general Broadcast Push Notifications.  They are great, but sometimes PushWoosh takes longer to deliver.  Parse is usually faster so the bottom line is I think Parse's Push Notifications are reliable.

Comment: this is just implementing Push Notifications the way Parse.com describes? No special methods? I am wondering if it's due to slow wifi...

Comment: also are you using the free Parse service or paid?

Comment: I'm using the free Parse service.  It's now free until you reach 1 million users.

Comment: It's looks okay as compared to the code I'm using with the exception of `- (void)notifyFriendAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(userCompletionHandler)handler`.  Where are you calling this in your code?

Comment: I took a second look at your code.  Try commenting out `currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];` and see if that makes a difference.  It looks like you're setting a channel but not pushing to that channel with your PFPush.

Comment: commented it out, hasn't made a difference...I call notifyFriendAtIndex when a cell is tapped on in a UITableView

Comment: re: the free till you reach 1 million users. This is very inaccurate and a  fresh read of the Parse offerings would be in order. ;) cheers.

Comment: What has changed in your reading of their prices?  It still looks like regarding Push Notifications that you can have up to 1 million unique users before you have to pay them anything.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, i concluded that most is due the main push notification deliverer ( Apple for iOS, Google for Android ). I'm saying this because we have an app in Parse that send push notification on both iOS and Android, and some days we don't receive any push notification, some others a few or all. All this without changing any implementation. In past, i used another push notification service called Urban Airship (that rely on the proper push notification deliverers), and there was the same problem, some days "almost" ok, some other no work.

Just check if your testing device are correctly registered in the "Installation" table with proper deviceToken set. We send the push notification server side through channels. I write here the code maybe it could help you:

```
   var dataStruct ={
                        alert: "Hi there!",                            
                        my_additional_info: "normal chat message"
                    };

    Parse.Push.send({
            channels: ["your_custom_registered_installation_channel_device"],
            data: dataStruct
        }).then(function() {
            promise.resolve();
        }, function(error) {
            promise.reject(error);        
    });
```

So normally it depends by the day, but if you have this statistic (50%) maybe the installation is not always registered/updated when your iPhone register for push notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{        
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    // Save/update device tocken
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    // store your channel 
    [currentInstallation setChannels:@["channel_123"]];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        // Do your stuff
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to mimic a push notification? Just wondering. That YO app uses push notifications all the time, it's supposed to be a reputable app with investors but seems odd if half the time the notifications won't even go through...

Comment: i've edited the answer with more info also for the iOS part. Anyway, from your Parse web dashboard, go on the top menu and click "Push". then on the top right there is the button "Send a push". Click it and you should be able send a push notification to one or more users querying them

Comment: @Kex Yes it seems correct, i suppose you're supporting iOS8+ since you're using '[application registerForRemoteNotifications]'. I've never sent push notification from client side, so i don't know if you need to use also the [push setChannel:@"global"] or not

Comment: I might have fixed it actually....when pasting the code I noticed that userinfo was on a new line and not next to (NSDictionary*), maybe I accidentally hit return. Not sure why Xcode let me compile that though...and not sure why it would make a difference. Anyway I have corrected it. Just spend 20 mins testing so far have a 100% success rate! Don't want to say for sure just yet it's fixed might just be a fluke but this is a dramatic change. Never had 100% before. Fingers crossed......odd error

Comment: a fluke...back down to about 50%...maybe it's dependent on the time of the day and more busy in the evening or something..

Comment: If you're sure no push relevant implementation is changed since this morning, i think that's just the traffic managed by parse and then by the push deliverers

Comment: the parse website has the "push" section on the control panel and it says in there if the individual pushes have been delivered or not. is there anyway to access this via the api and if the push is not sent try and push again?

Comment: From what i know, i don't think so. I've never check exactly for that, so maybe exist some way to obtain this, i don't know